# How do I use hasClass to detect if a class is NOT the class I want?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use hasClass so it works as doesNotHaveClass?  In other words, rather than looking to see if it is a specified class, looking to see if it is NOT a specified class.  Can I use an exclamation point or something like that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
if (!$('element').hasClass('do-not-want')) {
    // This element does not have the .do-not-want class
}
```

Answer (score 9):

However if you're trying to use selectors to find all the items that don't have a class, perhaps try this:

```
// find all divs that don't have "badClass" class    
$('div').not('.badClass').each(function(){});
```

Comment: +1 On a side note the pure selector syntax would be `div:not(.badClass)`

Comment: Thanks! That's actually really good to know - there are so many advanced selectors that I typically just chain them in non-performance intensive code. The :not syntax is definitely one that I'll remember though!

Answer (score 5):

```
if (!$('a').hasClass('xyz')){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can 
As per the jQuery documentation:

> The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an element, even if other classes also are.

Since the function returns a boolean you can use exclamation point to negate the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the return is false:

```
if($(element).hasClass("class") === false) {...}
```