# Safest way to select all radio buttons without a value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

http://jsfiddle.net/CuURK/

I have a number of radio buttons like:

```
<input type='radio' name='myradio' id='myradio' />
```

I need to select all radio buttons without a value attribute in the markup, and then set the attribute for these. The following tests don't work:

```
$('#myradio').val() // returns 'on'
$('#myradio').attr('value') // returns 'on'
```

This appears works in Chrome, but not IE8:

```
$('#myradio').is('[value]'); //doesn't work in IE8
```

What's the safest way to determine if an element has a value attribute? Is there an explanation for the above behaviour?

Comment: $(":radio[value]") will select all radio buttons with value attribute and $("radio").not(":radio[value]") will select all radio buttons without value attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The best and fastest way is to stick to CSS selectors:

```
$('input[type="radio"]:not([value])')
```

will return all'`input` elements that are `radio` **without** the attribute `value` present — [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fS9EN/1/).

Since it returns a collection you can do whatever you want, like adding the missing attribute, adding a class, hiding or removing the elements, without the need of a `.each()` loop, because most of jQuery's methods can work on collections — [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fS9EN/2/).

So in your case to add the missing attribute:

```
$('input[type="radio"]:not([value])').attr('value', 'foobar');
```

Remember that the selector is a valid CSS3 selector.

---

Update:

According to [this](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-selector-browser-support/#ie8notes) our selector will never match in IE8, since IE8 can't match using `[attr]` if the given attr is empty (and we're trying to match that).

So we have to loop over the `input`s and check if the attribute `value` is equal to `''`, since if it's missing jQuery return an empty string.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fS9EN/7), that kinda works on IE8 (I was able to try it on a real IE8).

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function (index, element) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.get(0).outerHTML.indexOf('value') === -1) {
        $this.addClass('found');
    }
});
```

For each element we check if its `outerHTML` property contains the `value` string. If it **doesn't** contain the string, we found it.
As you'll see, it only fails with a node like this:

```
<input type="radio" value />
```

because IE parses it as:

```
<input type="radio" />
```

It's not the efficient solution, but it works.

By the way, as I said in the comments, an `input` with `type="radio"` is [required to have the `value` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4). If it doesn't, the document is invalid, and browser may try to *correct* the document tree – Firefox appears to add a default value of `on`, while Safari doesn't.

Finally, jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) returns `undefined` if the attribute searched doesn't exist ([see the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L334)): so *generally* you could check for

```
typeof $('#foo').attr('attributeName') === 'undefined'
```

to see if the element has the `attributeName` attribute.

Comment: Try opening your first fiddle in IE8 - unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: `.attr('value')` returns 'on' for elements that have no value specified in the markup - see question.

Comment: According to the specs (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4), a `radio` `input` is required to have the `value` attribute, so browsers may add a default value of `on` (Firefox does it) or not (Safari doesn't) while the parse the tree. However, since the attribute on the DOM element doesn't exist, if we invoke `getAttribute('value')` on the element, we get back `null`. That said, this fiddle appears to work on Firefox and Safari: I didn't try it on IE8  http://jsfiddle.net/fS9EN/6/

Comment: I tried this, but it appears `getAttribute` is also broken for `'value'` on IE8 and earlier. Unfortunately I am writing for a corporate intranet running IE8.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
$('input[type="radio"]:not([value])')
```

As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/4sLzc/1/

The reason that `.val()` returns "on" is because it is default behaviour for a radio button without a value attribute to return "on". This is not a jQuery thing: the same thing happens with plain JavaScript if you say `document.getElementById("myradio").value`, or when the form is submitted you'd find server-side that "on" is the actual submitted value.

Comment: Ok, so why does `:not([value])` work if the value is `on`? I would have though if `.attr('value')` returns `on`, then `[value]` would have the same effect.

Comment: The value _property_ is `on`, and this is what `.val()` returns. `input[type="radio"]:not([value])` is basically a CSS selector that specifies the value _attribute_. I'm not sure what jQuery's `.attr('value')` is doing here because it seems to be returning the property rather than the attribute and I thought it was only supposed to do that with boolean properties. If you use a basic DOM element `.getAttribute('value')` it returns `null` if the attribute isn't there.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems '[value]' doesn't work in IE8 (it thinks the elements have value 'on'). Try opening your fiddle in IE8. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This would match for elements that have a value attribute

```
$('input[value]');
```

and this for ones that don't

```
$('!input[value]');
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Also you should use `:radio`.

Comment: You know its mentioned a lot in their docs but I don't think it has its own page, searching for ! on their site shows lots of examples though, here's one: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: That example is `!=` - not the same as putting a `!` at the beginning.

Comment: Indeed it is not, but there are lots of examples (not on the jQuery site strangely) of this in use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521660/how-do-i-use-hasclass-to-detect-if-a-class-is-not-the-class-i-want

Comment: That second example doesn't put `!` in the _selector_, it is applying `!` to the return value of a _function_.