# jquery if $this has not ClassName do action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see many answers but none of them seem to be working.

All my buttons have the "Trev" class. I want to check if the clicked class, also contains the "Namdons" class, and if so, do some code. However if not, do some code.

Some code that half works is:

```
$(".Trev").click
(
    function(e) 
    {

        if($(this).hasClass("Namdons")) 
        {
            console.log("Namdons");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Asdf");
        }
        e.preventDefault();

    }
);
```

However the "else" condition is not executing.

I've tried:

```
$(".Trev").click
(
    function(e) 
    {

        if($(this).hasClass("Namdons")) 
        {
            console.log("Namdons");
        }
        if(!$(this).hasClass("Namdons"))   //added apostrophe
        {
            console.log("Asdf");
        }
        e.preventDefault();

    }
);
```

as per these pages:

[How to check if an element does NOT have a specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841048/how-to-check-if-an-element-does-not-have-a-specific-class)
[How do I use hasClass to detect if a class is NOT the class I want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521660/how-do-i-use-hasclass-to-detect-if-a-class-is-not-the-class-i-want)

The "not" command does not apply as I'm only wanting to procure a single element and not select a bunch of them. Explained more on those pages.

HTML:

```
<div class="Trev Width50" onclick="Button('buttonname')"></div>
```

and

```
<button onclick="Namdons()" class="Namdons Trev TextAlignCenter">ButtonTitle</button>
```

also tried changing the Width50 div to a button:

```
<button class="Trev Width50" onclick="Button('buttonname')"></button>
```

There also doesn't seem to be an "elseif" in javascript is that correct?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: `$(this).hasClass('Namdons')` is only going to return true if that single element has the class.  I'm not sure I understand your statement about "as I'm only want to procure a single element and not select a bunch of them".  Because you are not doing that.

Comment: `else if` in javascript => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else?#Using_else_if

Comment: add html please

Comment: Taplar: It was an explanation as to why I don't want to use the "not" case operator. Added HTML.

Comment: why are you using an onclick if you're preventing that behaviour?

Comment: Sorry. I'd thought preventdefault only attributes to a page refresh.

Comment: @doodj7463 not if you make it a `type="button"` :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you tag `javascript` I put example in vanilla js. I leave it for you to translate it to jQuery. I also put notes inside:

```js
const trev = document.querySelectorAll('button.trev'); // get button with .trev style
for (var i=0; i < trev.length; i++) { // iterate them
  trev[i].addEventListener('click', function() { // add click event
    if (this.classList.contains('Namdons')) {alert('This is .Namdons');} // if it has .Namdons alert it
    else {alert('This is NOT .Namdons');} // it not alert that
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="Trev TextAlignCenter">ButtonTitle</button>
<button class="Namdons Trev TextAlignCenter">ButtonTitle</button>
<button class="Trev TextAlignCenter">ButtonTitle</button>
<button class="Namdons Trev TextAlignCenter">ButtonTitle</button>
<button class="Trev TextAlignCenter">ButtonTitle</button>
```

Read more about classList on [MDN](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: This worked, and so did the original code I posted. Turns out I had the Namdons buttons being echo'd from php, whereas the other buttons were being scripted in via a js.append(buttons) script. Then there was a settimeout on this of 50ms, meaning the coded javascript I was trying to use to select, wasn't selecting because the echo'd html from php wasn't rendered in the DOM yet. Thank you for your solution though. I prefer javacsript. Seems smoother.

Comment: Glad i could help.